# Is the Arrow of Time inviolable in Islamic belief?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, time

I know that Quran and Sunnah established that time is relative, e.g. a year of our time equals a different amount in heavens, or the story about the jinn moving Balqis's throne in he blink of the eye, or the Prophet's covering great distance in a short time during Isra' Mi'raj, or the story of the Companions of the Cave.

But in all of the stories I've found within the Islamic creed, all of them seem to observe the arrow of time. I don't recall any stories within the Islamic mythos that talks about any entity time-travelling backwards to its past. Am I correct?

Comment: I seem to recall there are ahadith that Muhammad saw the end times; if that means he travelled to the future, then he must've travelled back to the 7th century CE after so he could get back.

Comment: @G.Bach The prophet travelled to the future?

Answer (score -3):

i have found [a new interpretation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/37137) of [quran 18:86-90](https://quran.com/18/83-93) :

"Sahih International" translation :

> Until, when he reached the setting of the sun, he found it [as if]
>   setting in a spring of dark mud, and he found near it a people. Allah
>   said, "O Dhul-Qarnayn, either you punish [them] or else adopt among
>   them [a way of] goodness." ... Then he followed a way Until, when he
>   came to the rising of the sun, he found it rising on a people for whom
>   We had not made against it any shield.

as it is about zul-qarnayn went to time when the sun started to glow (past), *after* he went to time, when the sun falled to black hole (future).

any star, when starts to glow, [glows weakly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star#Main_sequence) compared to how it glows later:

> Starting at zero-age main sequence, the proportion of helium in a
>   star's core will steadily increase, the rate of nuclear fusion at the
>   core will slowly increase, as will the star's temperature and
>   luminosity. The Sun, for example, is estimated to have increased in
>   luminosity by about 40% since it reached the main sequence 4.6 billion
>   (4.6 × 109) years ago.

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate as I don't see any relation neither between the Wikipedia link and the verse 18:90 nor your answer and the actual question.